# Why error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" appears

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am converting a string type field to a date to be in '***yyyy-mm-dd***' using
`convert(date,[field_name],101) AS ChangeDate`

I have been using the same syntax in other queries and it works, but not this time.

I tried using `convert(datetime2,[field_name] AS ChangeDate` also producing the same error.
Below is the intended result with ChangeDate to be in the desired date format.

| Item | Date | ChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 20201016 | 2020-10-16 |
| 0002 | 20201203 | 2020-12-03 |
| 0003 | 20211108 | 2021-11-08 |
| 0004 | 20191229 | 2019-12-29 |
| 0003 | 20211122 | 2021-11-22 |
| 0004 | 20191229 | 2019-12-29 |

The result does appears for few second before the error popup as below:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: From the documentation, format 101 is `mm/dd/yyyy` not `yyyymmdd`. Format 112 appears to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @DaleK, the other queries also I've been using the same syntax and expression, and producing the result as mentioned above. However, changing 101 to 103/105 and others also still giving the same error.

Comment: That fact that its worked before isn't really relevant, you were lucky I guess SQL Server managed to guess for the data provided. Note I said format 112 - not 103/105. You don't need to be guessing here, check the documentation and use the correct format for your data.

Comment: And if 112 doesn't work, then I suspect you have bad data... which is one of the many issues you get when storing dates as strings.

Comment: _Conversion failed_ probably means that there is a date string that is not in the expected format. It is usually not a good idea to store dates as strings. You should use the appropriate [date type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @DaleK, yes. I tried 112, 23 also same. Sorry, but I am not guessing. I tried everything as in https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ in Date Only Formats.

Comment: Exactly, you shouldn't be trying everything (that is guessing) you should know the format of your data, and pick the correct single conversion for it. And given the sample data the problem is not reproducible. And the document is not the official docs - so may be correct, but usually better to go to the source.

Comment: Your sample data does not cause that error see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd7a6adaca8843da906023cbcce06d84)

Comment: @Abra, yes probably. This was done by someone else before this.

Comment: @DaleK great to know that, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISDATE(field_name)=1 THEN CONVERT(datetime, field_name, 103 ) 
        ELSE null 
    END
FROM your_table
```

I think you need to check that your date is correct and after that convert it.
You have a problem with your data.

Another solution:

Instead of convert use try_convert function:

```
try_convert(date,field_name,101) AS ChangeDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works! Upon checking in the database design, I found that there is "Allow Nulls = Yes" for this table. While for the other that I mentioned "have been using the same syntax in other queries and it works" is "Allow Nulls = No". Lol.

Comment: However, the try_convert is also producing the above error. Better to use those with the condition.